# Xamarin Plaid OAuth - Does Xamarin's WebAuthenticator support redirects with https://?

Tags: c#, xamarin, oauth-2.0, plaid, xamarin.essentials

I am trying to implement the banking Plaid OAuth portion of the API into my Xamarin app and have had plenty of troubles. For starters, Plaid requires an OAuth callback URL of `https://yoururlhere.com` which I cannot figure out for the life of me, if WebAuthenticator supports it. I have only seen examples of the `packagename`

Plaid does allow Android package names but not iOS... Should I be doing that instead? What happens then with iOS? I need to implement this for both Android and iOS. From my understanding, I am not leaving my Xamarin app as this is all done through a webview, therefore it doesnt really make sense to follow this approach correct?

To get a better sense of what I am trying to do, I have simplified my code and names below.
**MainViewModel.cs**

```
// successfully has linkToken before this point

var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
    new Uri("https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link.html?isWebview=true&token=" + linkToken),
    new Uri("https://someurl.net/link/v2/oauth/redirect")
);
```

**WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity.cs**.

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
     Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
     DataScheme = "https")]
public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
{
     public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
     {
          base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
     }
}
```

What should my datascheme be here? Just `https://`? or is it my full URL?

**AndroidManifest.xaml**
I have added the correct necessities here
I have not had a chance to look at the iOS necessities but we can ignore those for now.

I will also need to intercept this callback and make new http requests from the redirected URL to finalize the token, I am not sure how to do that either

Any help with implementing any part of this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft document provide the example about [Xamarin.Essentials： Web Authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android)

For Android, Android requires an Intent Filter setup to handle your callback URI. This is easily accomplished by subclassing the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity class.

```
const string CALLBACK_SCHEME = "myapp";

[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataScheme = CALLBACK_SCHEME)]
public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
{
}
```